# Javascript process batch promises progressively

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am currently in need of executing a large number of queries (1000) to various endpoints. The first approach I have tried is to store all `fetch` `promises` in an `array`, then to wait for `Promise.allSettled()` for all the responses to come in, and I later process the responses through a `for` loop.

The second approach which I tried (which I thought would be faster) was to process the data within the `promise`, so that I did not have to wait for all the responses to come through first. Here are my two approaches:

```
async function APPROACH_1() {
  const endpoints = []

  const batchPromises = []

  for(var i = 0; i < endpoints.length; i++) {
    batchPromises.push(fetch(endpoints[i]))
  }

  const resolvedPromises = await Promise.allSettled(batchPromises)
  const responses = resolvedPromises.map((r) => r.value)

  for(var i = 0; i < responses.length; i++) {
    // Process responses
  }
}

async function APPROACH_2() {
  const endpoints = []

  const batchPromises = []

  for(var i = 0; i < endpoints.length; i++) {
    batchPromises.push(fetch(endpoints[i]).then((v) => {
      // Process response
    }))
  }

  const resolvedPromises = await Promise.allSettled(batchPromises)
  const processedResponses = resolvedPromises.map((r) => r.value)

}
```

Surprisingly enough, the first approach looks to be faster while benchmarking. Thus, I probably have not achieved what I am trying to do. I am trying to process the data progressively as each response is coming in, and not have to wait for each response promise to be resolved.

Comment: How do you process each response?

Comment: @eol I have to check if the response object contains certain parameters.

Comment: don't forget you can also use `.map` to create the array of promises instead of the `for / push` anti-pattern.

Comment: @Alnitak Thanks for the tip. Do you know the answer to the original question though?

Comment: I think there's a good question lurking in here, but I'd like to make it explicit.  If we have N promise chains, that are M long, should we do all the links in lockstep (N promises together, M times), or all the chains together (N promise chains of length M)?  In this form, the M steps in the chains would be async also.

Comment: What is involved in processing the response?  Is it entirely synchronous code or are there asynchronous operations involved in the processing of a response?  How many endpoints are there (approximately)?

Comment: @jfriend00 The processing is not asynchronous. It involves checking if each response object has particular parameter values. There are approximately 1000 endpoints.

Comment: It seems you "could" benefit from doing the processing when the response arrives because you will be able to use initial CPU cycles that would otherwise go unused while waiting for all the responses to arrive.  If this is not what you find when you measure, then there is something else influencing things that you would need to diagnose.  Using unused CPU cycles should not slow things down on its own.

Comment: 1000 requests in a parallel (all sent to the same host at the same time) may cause some inefficiencies on the receiving host as it either tries to process all 1000 at once (perhaps in a bunch of threads) or rate limits you because you're sending too many simultaneous requests or slows down a target database by trying to run too many simultaneous DB requests. In an I/O bound process, there can be a limit to how many simultaneous requests are efficient, beyond which the time per request gets worse.

Comment: @jfriend00 also the browser _should_ limit the maximum number of concurrent requests to any particular hostname.

Comment: @Alnitak - If this is browser code, the  browser will limit the number of requests to the same host.  But, this is tagged as nodejs code where no such limit exists and there are `fetch()` libraries for nodejs.

Comment: @jfriend00 duh, yes, of course - I didn't spot the tag.